# (document).ready(function () isn't running the function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this basic function which is supposed to run when the page is loaded, however it doesn't seem to be called. I know that the function is correct as it run perfectly when using `$('window').resize`

The function is and is being called at the end of the page followed only by the `$(window).resize` version of the function and `</body>`;

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sliderImgH = $(".sliderimages").height();
        $(".buttonmove:nth-child(1)").css("margin-top", sliderImgH-75);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does `$(".sliderimages")` return a collection or single element ? What does `$(".sliderimages").height();` return ?

Comment: @guest271314 its for multiple elements in my slider, it returns the height of the images

Comment: If it's returning multiple elements shouldn't you use `each()` then?

Comment: @Machavity ther're all the same height, however re-size when the page does, so the height value is always changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try selecting first `.sliderimages` element using `:first`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sliderImgH = $(".sliderimages:first").height();
    $(".buttonmove:nth-child(1)").css("margin-top", sliderImgH-75);
});
```

Comment: that still doesn't work, here is the link to the site, I'm just trying to move the slider buttons so it is over the slider images,  http://optential.co.nf/

Comment: @MattHammond Can describe _"still doesn't work"_ ? , include `html` from link at Question ?, create stacksnippets, http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: how strange it seems to work in here - https://jsfiddle.net/aL1jk855/

Comment: Ive fixed it, I had another function above it which seemed to be cause the issue, thank you for your help and sorry for wasting your time!